# How can i customize the floating button like the Android messages App?

Tags: android, floating-action-button

How to achieve this?

[image]

How to get the floating button like in the bottom?

is there any good and reliable library for this?

Answer (score -1):

You can refer to [this](https://github.com/cometchat-pro/android-java-chat-app)  project it has exactly what you need full code to make the extended fab

or you can refer to [this](https://github.com/aniketbhoite/MutativeFab) library  called Mutative Fab written in kotlin  which helps you achieve the same